# How to prevent subprocess to add spaces between some parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'd like to execute some Mysql commands from Linux, using Python and its `subprocess` module.

**Without Python**, from a shell, my command line is:

```
mysql --database=mydb --host=localhost --port=3306 --password=  --execute="select * from mytable" --batch
```

**With Python**, I have:

```
cmd = ['mysql']
cmd.extend(['--database=', self._database])
cmd.extend(['--password=', self._password])
cmd.extend(['--execute=', query])

(...)

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
errcode = p.returncode
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work (mysql just print usage) and I *think*, subprocess generate this kind of output (`' '.join(cmd)`):

```
mysql --database= mydb --host= localhost --port= 3306 --password=  --execute= "select * from mytable" --batch
```

ie. spaces are added between each parameters, separating `=` and value.

When I remove `=` in every parameters (`cmd.extend(['--password', self._password])`), it works fine, except when a parameter is void (so, I test if each parameter is void, then remove it if needed).

Finally, I found a workaround, by testing void parameters, but for future reference, is there any subprocess tip or usage I don't know to handle this kind of `parameter=` ? There must be some application when you *have to* use `=`, and I try to avoid `Shell=True`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change that to

```
cmd = [
    'mysql',
    '--database=%s' % self._database,
    '--password=%s' % self._password,
    '--execute=%s' % query
]

(...)

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
errcode = p.returncode
```

such that the list of arguments contains switches with their respective arguments

Comment: So simple, yet, I didn't even think of that (I guess I need vacation :) ) Thank you

Comment: I like, but how about removing the extend and just do `['mysql', '--database=%s' % self._database, ...]` while we're at it?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing each argument containing an `=` sign as two separate arguments. Don't do that, because they're not two separate arguments.

```
cmd.append('--database=' + self._database)
cmd.append('--password='+ self._password)
cmd.append('--execute=' + query)
```

(David's suggestion to use `[]` to define the whole list at once rather than repeated `append` or `extend` calls is better style.)